# Oracle Get Information for people who have rented a movie

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the mm_member and mm_rental tables, write a query that will list all members (member ID, first name, and last name) and the number of movies they have rented, for all members who have rented at least one movie. Order the result set so that it shows the largest number of movies rented as the first row.

I have been struggling with this problem for my class for a few hours now so I am looking for some help.

Here is what I have:

```
    SELECT mm_member.member_id, mm_member.last, mm_member.first, count(mm_rental.member_id)
    FROM mm_member, mm_rental
    WHERE mm_member.member_id = mm_rental.member_id
    AND count(mm_rental.member_id) > 0
    ORDER BY count(mm_rental.member_id);
```

I get the error: ORA-00934: group function not allowed here.

I will gladly provide the entire database file if needed just let me know!

Comment: If you solved your problem, don't forget to close it or mark the answer as accepted in order to remove this question from the unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the aggregate function `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY` clause. Here is your query with the missing clause:

```
SELECT M.member_id
    ,M.last
    ,M.first
    ,COUNT(R.member_id) AS "nb_movies"
FROM mm_member M
INNER JOIN mm_rental R ON R.member_id = M.member_id
GROUP BY M.member_id, M.last, M.first
ORDER BY COUNT(R.member_id) DESC
```

I also changed your query in order to use the `INNER JOIN` clause instead of old school jointure syntax (i suggest you to avoid this syntax).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Your answer gives me an error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not where expected.

I tried changing your [nb_movies] to "nb_movies" and then I get a result that looks somewhat correct. Thank you very much! If you adjust your answer I will mark it as correct!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i fixed my query. Happy to see that it helps to solve your problem

Comment: @xCasper Don't forget to mark the Question as answered to remove it from the unanswered list